# Change color of button during keypress

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the color of a

```
<input type='button' class='button'>
```

when it is clicked by a mouse or while pressing the enter key.

To change the color when clicked by mouse I can simply use the following css

```
.button:active{
   background-color:#FFF;
}
```

For the enter key, I tried the following jQuery code:

```
$('.button').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.which == 13){
          $(this).css('background-color','#FFF')
      }
  });
```

But this doesnt work, now the background remains white after hitting return. However, I only want the background to get white **during** the time someone hits enter. How can I achive this?

Comment: `keydown` instead of `keypress`?

Comment: @RGraham it does not work if I replace keypress by keydown. Having the same problem as described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of keypress/keyup to toggle the color:

```js
$("button").keydown(function(e) {
    // Sets the color when the key is down...
    if(e.which === 13) {
     $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    }
});
$("button").keyup(function() {
    // Removes the color when any key is lifted...
    $(this).css("background-color", "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
Test
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think you are missing a dot in **$(".button")**.

Comment: @Adam That's a selector for any `<button>` element :) `.button` would select any element with `class="button"`

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
.clicked{
background:#fff !important;
}

$('.button').keydown(function(e){
      if(e.which == 13){
           $(this).addClass('clicked');
        }
 e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: but then I need to remove the class clicked on keyup or something right?

Comment: no need to remove.. oR  $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('clicked');

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code

```
           $('.button').keypress(function(e){
              if(e.which == 13){
                  $(this).css('background-color','#FFF');
              }
            });

            $('.button').keyup(function(e){
              if(e.which == 13){
                  $(this).css('background-color','');
              }
            });
```